# How to use of certificates in ios

Tags: ios, xcode

Recently my client gives me access to his `"developer.apple"` account and told me to use it for further development for his existing project. But still now, i was develop with another `"developer.apple"` account. In client account all certificates and profile (certificates, identifiers, devices, provisioning profiles ) are ready. Now my question is should i create a new profile (with my keychain request file) for my device as well as iPhone or iPad to develop this project or i could use his certificate as usually by downloading it. Besides if any one give me some tutorials or links about Details about apple certificates and how to use it in devices (mac & iPhone/iPad) and how does it works with xcode, that will be much appreciable. I am new here in iOS..

Thanks, Have a good day..

Comment: Read this http://mobiforge.com/design-development/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices

Comment: ok, i am looking on it. Thanks for commenting. @James Webster

Comment: I didn't comment, I edited to remove some tags: You should use [iphone] and [ipad] to refer to the hardware only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with `XCode5` then things are easy now. Just log in to your new apple developer account using `Accounts` section in `XCode5`.

Press `CMD + ,` on `XCode` or go to `preferences` and select `Accounts`. You can see there your already logged-in account and using bottom option `Add Apple ID` add your new apple id there. Other things will be automatically done along with your `keychain certs` and `provisioning profiles`.
[image]

And after this again go to `XCode` general section and choose your newly added developer account.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to create new provisioning profile. You can use the client' profile. But you have to import the private keys(from the client) in your system. Some nice tutorials are

http://www.mytechspace.com/2012/04/step-by-step-procedure-to-deploy-iphone.html

http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1

Comment: Do you mean the "keychain private keys" of client?